# Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I have an `RScript` file (let's call it `main.r`) which has a reference to another file, using the below code:

```
source("functions.R")
```

But, when I run the RScript file, it complains with the below error:

```
    Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
      cannot open the connection
    In addition: Warning message:
    In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
      cannot open file 'functions.R': No such file or directory
```

I am sure, my `main.R` file is next to `functions.R` in the same directory.
I can call the `functions.R` in the `Rmd` (`RMarkdown`) file which exist in the same directory

Comment: Did you set the working directory in `main`?

Comment: I don't know, what is it. Can you please give more details?
I have tried this one as well `source("./functions.R")`

Comment: i had the same issue, i resolved it by modifying the file i was doing source() on. That file also was calling a source() on a file that wasn't there. ( i had moved directories and forgot to copy over that other file)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your case try to add `setwd("path/to/project/")` in `main.R` where `path/to/project/` contains `main.R`.

Then you can `source` `functions.R` either directly by `source("functions.R")` if both files lie in the same directory or `source("sub-folder/functions.R")` if the latter file is contained in a sub-folder.

If you're not working on a `RStudio` project, chances are the working directory of `main.R` might be your home directory.

Comment: is it an absolute path? or it can be relational? i have tried `source("./functions.R")`

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara I believe it depends on your home directory (or your script's current directory). If you have for instance a `RStudio` project then the path will be by default the project's path. Then you can reference a relational path. Or if `/functions.R` is a sub-directory of your home directory that should work as well.

Comment: Hi niko, I have the same issue but I am really lost in my code, can you write an example or tell me where write setwd. I put this: ```{r echo=FALSE}
source("C:/Users/myname/Documents/R/data/myfunction.R").
```. But still doesn't run.

Answer (score 2):

If the file you source ALSO uses `source("...")` to reference other files, you will get this same error.

For example:

1. Your working directory is `getwd()` `".../projectA"`
2. You have another file you want to reference from another R Project called `functions.R`. So you try to source this `source(".../projectB/functions.R")`. This results in the error.
3. It's because contained in the code of `functions.R` is `source("helper_functions.R")`. But your source is using the original path (e.g., `.../projectA/`), not the project path of `functions.R` (e.g., `.../projectB/`)